# Backticks in readable markdown links should be stripped

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

I am frequently using readable links, e.g.:

```
[James Gosling], working at [Sun] by that time, written the [`URL`] class.

[James Gosling]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling
[sun]: http://www.oracle.com/us/sun/index.html
[URL]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html
```

Both "*James Gosling*" and "*Sun*" links are properly resolved (note that the link is actually named "*sun*"). However the "*URL*" is not because of the extra backticks - and I use such combination of backticks and links often when referring to external code documentation. Obviously I can do:

```
[`URL`][URL]
```

but it would be nice if SO engine could strip these extra characters automatically.

Comment: As an aside: other formatting such as emphasis *is* supported, but then needs that formatting in both the text and its reference. Like `[James **Gosling**] working at [_Sun_]` together with `[james **gosling**]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling` and `[_sun_]: http://www.oracle.com/us/sun/index.html` works fine. (Though one could argue if the need to repeat formatting in the reference is to be expected.) But not so much for the backticks.